# Adding a package immediately after created by create-react-app is not working

Tags: macos, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am very new to react (started a day ago). I used the create-react-app command line to create an app. I tried in the following order

- create-react-app my-app
- npm start

At this point the app is running fine. Then I did the following

- npm install youtube-api-search
- npm start

Now i am getting this error

> my-app@0.1.0 start /Users/shanmugharajk/Code/udemy/my-app
> react-scripts start

> sh: react-scripts: command not found npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! code
> ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR!
> my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! spawn ENOENT npm
> ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This
> is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> output above.

This happens every single time with any package I try to install.

One think I noted is when i run

- npm install youtube-api-search or any pckage it always removes some package. The message I am getting while installing any package is

> npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/
> because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline? npm WARN registry
> Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous
> Warning ENOTFOUND: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/redux failed,
> reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
> registry.npmjs.org:443 npm WARN registry Using stale package data from
> https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during
> revalidation. npm WARN gentlyRm not removing
> /Users/shanmugharajk/Code/udemy/my-app/node_modules/html-minifier/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs
> as it wasn't installed by
> /Users/shanmugharajk/Code/udemy/my-app/node_modules/html-minifier/node_modules/uglify-js
> npm WARN gentlyRm not removing
> /Users/shanmugharajk/Code/udemy/my-app/node_modules/espree/node_modules/.bin/acorn
> as it wasn't installed by
> /Users/shanmugharajk/Code/udemy/my-app/node_modules/espree/node_modules/acorn
> npm WARN gentlyRm not removing
> /Users/shanmugharajk/Code/udemy/my-app/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/.bin/browserslist
> as it wasn't installed by
> /Users/shanmugharajk/Code/udemy/my-app/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/browserslist
> npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit
> this file.
>
> - redux@3.7.1 added 3 packages, **removed 1142 packages and updated 3 packages in 27.043s**

I couldn't figure out the reason. Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using npm 5. At the moment it has many issues.

I recommend to downgrade to npm 4 and try again:

```
npm install -g npm@4

rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

If it doesn't help check your internet connection.
This looks like an issue with your network:

> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

Comment: Yes this is it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer, since I had yarn and npm both installed in my machine the create-react-app uses yarn and installs all the dependencies and creates yarn.lock file.

So now when I run npm install  it looks for package.lock.json and it wont be there. So it uninstalls some package creates by yarn at the time of creation of the project.

So the solution I found is do any of the following

> - create-react-app my-app
> - npm install
> - Then do install npm install -package-

Or

> - create-react-app my-app
> - yarn install -package-

Both of this approach is working now for me.

Comment: This solution is actually better instead of downgrading

Comment: Did not work for me, as I do not have yarn installed at all and yet I was still getting the "stale package" error.  @Dan Abramov's solution did work though.

Answer (score 0):

Basic requirement to run React app is:

```
 nodejs  
 npm
```

If it is not installed then install this by(specifically for Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

To create react js app:

```
npx create-react-app my-DemoApp
```

A
fter that go inside folder by:

```
cd my-DemoApp
```

You can see basic folder structure created by this

```
my-DemoApp
├── README.md
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    └── serviceWorker.js
```

After than add basic dependency required by react app by running:

```
npm install
```

That will create new folder named : `node_modules` in your parent folder

You can now run your app by :

```
npm start
```

And now you are done with most basic setup, you're app is now ready.

You also can add more library which is mandatory for the app by `npm`

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g npm

And then install create react app again:

npm install -g create-react-app

And then create the project again