# create-react-app can not run after install a module

Tags: reactjs

I created a React app by the command `create-react-app qiyujidemo`
I installed and can run the app well.
Then I installed a [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-weui) with `npm install weui@1.1.0 react-weui --save`.
After the module is installed, I type the `npm start`. 
Then, there is something wrong.

> > qiyujidemo@0.1.0 start /Users/yianwork/wechat/qiyujidemo
> >     react-scripts start
> >     sh: react-scripts: command not found
> >     npm ERR! file sh
> >     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> >     npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> >     npm ERR! syscall spawn
> >     npm ERR! qiyujidemo@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
> >     npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> >     npm ERR!
> >     npm ERR! Failed at the qiyujidemo@0.1.0 start script.
> >     npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> >     npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> >     npm ERR!     /Users/yianwork/.npm/_logs/2017-08-07T08_41_16_944Z-debug.log

I copy the /Users/yianwork/.npm/_logs/2017-08-07T08_41_16_944Z-debug.log.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.1.0_1/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.3
3 info using node@v8.1.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle qiyujidemo@0.1.0~prestart: qiyujidemo@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle qiyujidemo@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle qiyujidemo@0.1.0~start: qiyujidemo@0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle qiyujidemo@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle qiyujidemo@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/yianwork/wechat/qiyujidemo/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/yianwork/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/yianwork/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
10 verbose lifecycle qiyujidemo@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/yianwork/wechat/qiyujidemo
11 silly lifecycle qiyujidemo@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
12 info lifecycle qiyujidemo@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: qiyujidemo@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:33:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:887:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
14 verbose pkgid qiyujidemo@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/yianwork/wechat/qiyujidemo
16 verbose Darwin 16.4.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.1.0_1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.1.0
19 verbose npm  v5.0.3
20 error file sh
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error syscall spawn
24 error qiyujidemo@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
24 error spawn ENOENT
25 error Failed at the qiyujidemo@0.1.0 start script.
25 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I type the `yarn start`, then the following error is shown:

> yians-iMac:qiyujidemo yianwork$ yarn start
>   yarn start v0.24.5
>   $ react-scripts start
>   sh: react-scripts: command not found
>   error Command failed with exit code 127.

Who can solve this problem? What is wrong?

I create a new project by `create-react-app`. It runs well. Then I installed the React-router, and the same problem occurs. I uninstalled react-weui, but still it can't run.

**When I write the `yarn add antd` in the `create-react-app` demo, the project is run well.**  Must I use yarn to add a dependency?

Comment: Does it works again if you uninstall those packages ? `npm uninstall weui react-weui --save`

Comment: @Fawaz I create a new project by `create-react-app`. It runs well. Then I install the `npm install --save react-router`, and the same problem show.     I run the `npm uninstall weui react-weui --save` it can't run yet.

Comment: did you install create-react-app globally ? Did you clean your node_modules folders ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546231/sh-react-scripts-command-not-found-after-running-npm-start

Comment: @Nevosis As I can use the `create-react-app` in every folder, I think I install the create-react-app globally. I delete the node_modules and install again, the project can't run yet.

Comment: @jiexishede Are you writing the commands in the correct dir path ? like inside your project folder. After you do `create-react-app myApp` then you go into your app folder `cd myApp` and then do all the npm stuff.

Comment: @Fawaz  I insure I write the command in the correct dir path, because I can  run the `npm start` command.

Comment: @jiexishede Its also been reported that there are issues with npm v5 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860917/create-react-app-not-working?rq=1 So can you downgrade and check if that works like suggested in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) in your package.json? If not, install it and add the following to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build && cp CNAME build/CNAME",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```